# How to use a javascript var in a jinja loop

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

Inside the javascript part of my HTML file, I need to use jinja to loop over a passed JSON from flask.
However I need to break the loop when the index hits the value of a javascript var already existing.

```js
var username_selected = $('#username').find(":selected").text();
 {% for user in users if user.username == username_selected -%}
    var key = {{ user.keynumber }};
    $('#originalkey').val(key);
 {% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, this doesnt work and I assume its because jinja thinks that `username_selected` is a part of jinja but its not.

I tried to create a jinja variable with the JS var value but it didn't help.

```
{% set username = namespace(username=username_selected) %}
```

Is there any workaround for it or is it physically impossible?

Comment: It's completely impossible because jinja template code runs on the server, before the resulting HTML is sent to the browser and long before the browser start to run client-side <script>s. What you want to achieve all needs to happen client-side, so you need to pass along the server data to your client-side scripts. One way to do this: `const users = {{ users | jsonify }}` or similar.

Comment: Note that what you appear to call JSON is an object or array, but to insert it into your client-side JS code you actually need to turn it into JSON (i.e. text).

Comment: Here's how I solved this: https://pastebin.com/DrTNku8M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code given by [@Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DrTNku8M). Making sure of availability of code for future use also.

```
const users = {{ users | tojson | safe }}
```

```
$('#username').on('input', function () {
  const username_selected = $('#username').val();
  const user = users.find(user => user.username === username_selected);
  if (user) $('#originalkey').val(user.keynumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Python code runs on server and js in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by dropping the if condition in jinja loop and replacing it with javascript if condition and returning from the function when condition met.

```js
function update_userkey(){
    var username_selected = $('#username').find(":selected").text();
    {% for user in users -%}
    if( "{{user.username}}" == username_selected){
        var key = {{ user.keynumber }};
        $('#originalkey').val(key);
        return;
    }
    {% endfor %}
}
```

Comment: What function? This is not a suitable solution. SO is supposed to be an exhaustive FAQ, not a collection of individual workarounds. Future users who find this might use this code in their own project, and bad practice propagates.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for the issue I personally raised. It was just missing the function wrapper so I added it.

Comment: I doesn't matter that this is your personal issue; as soon as you post it here it becomes public and subject to SO's guidelines. An accepted answer is supposed to provide a best practice solution ideally, not a cobbled together workaround that produces tons of duplicate code. The proper solution is to provide a way for the client-side script to access the users array and populate the field based on an Array.find search, not a for loop containing dozens or hundreds of if blocks.